# How can I combine a warning message and update field value inside of onchange method? In odoo 9

Tags: odoo, warnings, odoo-9

In older versions of odoo (openerp 7), I used to do things like this:

```py
@api.multi
@api.onchange('my_field')
def my_field_change(self, cr, uid, partner_ids, context=None):
  if condition is True:
     return {
            'warning': {'title': _('Error'), 'message': _('Error message'),},
            'value': { 'my_field': new_value },
             }
```

If I want to do this in odoo 9, I have this code:

```py
@api.multi
@api.onchange('my_field')
def my_field_change(self):
  if condition is True:
     return {
            'warning': {'title': _('Error'), 'message': _('Error message'),},
            'value': { 'my_field': new_value },
             }
```

The warning window is displayed but the value field is ignored.

How can I change the value of the field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In odoo **Onchange** method, you can't return value same as older version of odoo.

Onchange method will only return Warning and Domain.

```py
@api.multi
@api.onchange('my_field')
def my_field_change(self):
    self.field=value
    return {
        'warning': {'title': _('Error'), 'message': _('Error message'),},
         }
```

In Odoo new api no need to return value in dict just assign value in relevant field.

**Ex: sale.field=value**

This may help you.